# How to get Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default without getting path null exception

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to use Firestore with a Xamarin cross platform project. When creating the FirestoreDb instance an ArgumentNullException is thrown -> Value cannot be null. From looking into the stack trace and the message it looks like the path returned from Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.ApplicationEnvironment.GetApplicationBasePath() is null. Does anyone know what I can do to get this to not return null? This only occurs on the Android project, running the code on the iOC

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 2.0 Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions package have been removed as it was no longer necessary to maintain this abstraction. https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/237